# Command add-apt-repository problems

Tags: apt, python, add-apt-repository

I'm trying to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

And getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

OK, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg), I'm removing and reinstalling python-apt and python3-apt, but then I get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Like [here](https://itsfoss.com/add-apt-repository-command-not-found/), I do:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

But then I get the same issue as the first one: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` and it all starts over. What should I do?

Comment: do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` work at all? I dunno what your terminal is on about saying `add-apt-repository` is an unknown command. sounds like something's very broken at a sytem level.